# How effective is it to default to user input in C++ function parameters?

Tags: c++

This defaults to user input if the arguments are not passed at compile time.. How effective is this technique and where can it be applied?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>

void foo(unsigned number = []() {unsigned num = 0; std::cin >> num; return num; } ()) {
    std::cout << number << "\n";
}


int main() {
    foo(1); //prints 1
    foo();  //defaults to user input    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with your `main` function parameter definition,, fix that please.

Comment: I do not see much benefit of this other than code being closer to the call site. Perhaps you could create more complex and concrete example that would better illustrate the advantages?

Comment: That's what I am asking for XD. Can you think of any?

Comment: This does not look [actual code from one of your projects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard, It isn't and I'm really sorry for that. But I wanted to know the implications of the code if I use it in my project. I know I've violated the guideline and should be 'fined' for that. I will be fine with it, even if you vote to close this question (which I guess you probably have). P.S. I will refrain from such questions in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen this pattern in use, and I wouldn't use it personally, for two reasons:

1) Unintuitive - Changing the function's behavior in this significant of a way is not something you'd expect from the default value of a parameter.

2) Mixing Concerns - It's almost always better to separate your I/O from your algorithm.

Considering that this is a compile-time difference anyway, it would be more clear to have another method to read input.  For example:

```
foo(1);
foo(foo_input());
```

Comment: Please don't take the code literally. I wanted to focus on the part wherein default arguments are user input. The definition may be different.

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case, point 2 applies even more-so.